# magento 2.1.9 new order email sometimes not sent

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm using Magento 2 for my webshop now for about 6 months and thats working fine (exept for some bugs that are solved). When a costumer orders and pays with Mollie Ideal (Dutch payment provider) an new order email goes to the costumer and myself.

The last 2 weeks in some cases the invoice is not being made and due to that also the new order email is nog being made. I can't find the root cause, sometimes it goes wright and sometimes not, strange...

Any ideas? Some tables or registers that are full maybe? Or someting with cronjobs?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure cron job is working fine. To check cron job status, install magento 2 schedular extension where its schedule every task by using scheduler.
If cron job stops working due to any error than it will shows warning in its scheduler page.

Thanks